# Obtener el numero siguiente utilizando JSF+PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf

Tengo el siguiente problema, que no se como resolver. Quiero que al realizar el alta en una tabla me proponga ya en la vista un numero siguiente. Logre armar la consulta, pero por algun motivo no se refresca en la vista. Tal vez alguien pueda indicarme cual es el problema que estoy teniendo:

```
 <p:outputLabel for="txtCuenta" value="Cuenta" />
                        <p:inputText id="txtCuenta" value="#{xxxController.cuenta.numero}" maxlength="05" size="05">
                            <p:ajax event="focus" update="txtCuenta" listener="#{xxxController.getUltimaCuenta}" />
                        </p:inputText>      
                        <p:message for="txtCuenta"></p:message>
```

Y en el xxxController tengo el metodo getUltimaCuenta, que funciona:

```
  public short getUltimaCuenta(){
    short numero=0; 
    numero=cuentaEJB.ultimo();
    numero++;
    return numero;
}
```

¿Cómo logro que el valor que devuelve el método `getUltimaCuenta` aparezca 
en el inputText txtCuenta y se almacene claro?

Comment: Siempre me he preguntado por qué este tipo de cosas son necesarias. Bueno, lo que puedes hacer es crear un registro ficticio en la bd y obtener el id auto generado. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es, si en tu bd usas una secuencia, obtener el siguiente valor de la secuencia y usar ese valor luego como el id a registrar en tu tabla.

Comment: Si te entendí bien.. `<outputLabel value="#{xxxController.ultimaCuenta}">`. Al ponerse el foco en el input, se llamará a `xxxController#getUltimaCuenta` y este actualizará el label `txtCuenta`. Es necesario crear la propiedad `ultimaCuenta` con su getter en el backing bean.

Comment: Adicional al aporte de @MitsuGami, considera que en JSF los métodos `getter` pueden llamarse más de una vez, por lo que **no se recomienda** que exista lógica de negocio ni en `get` ni en `set` de tus managed beans.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta MitsuG!,

sin embargo logre que se "actualizara" vista y me mostrara el numero siguiente,
pues el metodo se ejecutaba, solo que no aparaceria.
Agregando la siguientes lineas funciono como esperaba:

```
<p:focus context="pg"/>
```

Y asi quedo la vista:

```
 <h:form>
                <p:focus context="pg"/> 
                <p:messages id="mensaje" autoUpdate="false" severity="info,fatal" showSummary="false" showDetail="True"></p:messages>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Alta de Cuentas</legend>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="pg">
                        <p:outputLabel for="txtCuenta" value="Cuenta" />
                        <p:inputText id="txtCuenta" value="#{xxxController.cuenta.numero}" maxlength="05" size="05">
                            <f:ajax event="focus" listener="#{xxxController.getUltimaCuenta}" render="txtCuenta"/>                    
                        </p:inputText>      
                        <p:message for="txtCuenta"></p:message>
```

Gracias por tu tiempo, y buena disposicion!

Saludos
Fernando

Answer (score 0):

La lógica es sencilla. Veamos por pasos:

1. Escuchar por evento `focus`
2. Asociar a dicho evento, un método en el backing bean.
3. JSF ejecuta el método asociado en el backing bean y guarda el resultado de la operación en una variable.
4. Una vez guardado el valor, mediante el atributo `render` o `update` si estás usando PrimeFaces, se renderiza el valor obtenido de la ejecución del método en la etiqueta.

Ahora representemos esta lógica con código:

**Vista**

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{controller.ultimaCuenta}" />
<h:inputText>
  <f:ajax event="focus" render="txtCuenta"
          listener="#{controller.consultarUltimaCuenta()}" />
</h:inputText>
<p jsf:id="txtCuenta"></p> <!-- JSF 2.2 passtrough -->
```

**Backing bean**

```
private short ultimaCuenta;

...

public void consultarUltimaCuenta() {
    ultimaCuenta = EJBCuenta.ultimo();
}

public short getUltimaCuenta() {
    return ultimaCuenta;
}
```

Es importante la aclaración que te hizo @LuiggiMendoza:

> considera que en JSF los métodos getter pueden llamarse más de una
>   vez, por lo que no se recomienda que exista lógica de negocio ni en
>   get ni en set de tus managed beans.

Puedes ver la explicación [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times).